# Alfresco select max date created for child node property

Tags: java, alfresco

I am using the Alfresco Community Edition. Currently I am trying to develop a custom behavior for a node, where I take actions depending on the maximum creation date of the direct child nodes(not needed child of a child).

Is there a way to get the maximum creation date of a node's children via a query/method? I would like to avoid getting all the children and then, for each get the property - it seems rather ugly and potentially slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you are using java class to add that behaviour. For searching you could utilize SearchParameter class where you can sort resultset based on property.
So following code will help your to create search parameter which fetch sorted resultset(sorted based on creation date) for you.

```
SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
sp.setQuery(query);
sp.addStore(Repository.getStoreRef());
String field = org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.QueryParser.escape("@cm:created"); 
sp.addSort(org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.QueryParser.escape(field), false);
```

If you are using javascript by any chance then you could sort the result set as follow.In following query your search result will be sorted in decending order based on created Date.

```
var nodes = search.luceneSearch("TEXT:alfresco", "@cm:created", false);
```